# How to create component able to nesting other components

Tags: qt, qml

I want to create the frame with a header and container for other components.
It should look like the ColumnLayout. It nests other components and arranges them in a column.
And I need dynamically overlap nested components by code within the frame.

I try this code

```
ColumnLayout {
    id: root
    anchors.fill: parent

    TopRowButtons {
        id: topRowButtons
        height: root.height*0.15
    }

    Item {
        id: itemContaining
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        Layout.fillWidth: true
    }
}
```

But if I put other components into these components then the new components overlap topRowButtons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `default` keyword for a property alias which points to the `ColumnLayout.data` property, which I think you want swapped with the `Item` (because you are talking about overlapping the header). Also, the `TopRowButtons` should be lower in the code if you want them to appear above the contents:

```
Item {
    id: root

    default property alias subdata : itemContainer.data

    ColumnLayout {
        id: itemContainer
        anchors.fill: parent
    }

    TopRowButtons {
        id: topRowButtons
        height: root.height*0.15
    }
}
```

The `data` [property](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#data-prop) is the default property of the outer `ColumnLayout` and accepts any object, visual objects are parented to the `ColumnLayout`. You can also use the `children` property if you only want to allow visual objects to be nested